# How php act as agent server in getting the data and return the result to c#?

Tags: php, json, http

I working on a project where there is a(an) proxy/agent server in php, and it gets the Json from user using c#, and in turn the agent server will pass/post the end result to the user by using Json as well.Right after the agent server get the json and it will decode the key/value and eventually store the value to the variables.However,these variables will be send to the end server via http in order to process these variables at end server.Then, the end server will send the final result back upon its processing to agent server and thereby agent server will send/post the result as JSON to the user at the end of the date. 
The agent server may look like this:

```
<?php
 //get the data from user
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $json=file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data=json_decode($json);
    $amount=$data['currencyAmount'];
    $from=$data['currencyFrom'];
    $to=$data['currencyTo'];
    $total=$data['currencyResult'];

    //pass the data to url and send to the end server
    header("Location: http://xxxxx.netne.net/parsedata.php?amount=amount&from=from&to=to&total=total");

}else{

   echo 'error!';
}
```

The code above don't have the functionality of get the result from the end server via php and thereby post/send the result as JSON to the user.How to achieve all these  feature?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending GET request to the end sever, to make a HTTP GET request in PHP you have to use curl and return the response in $content.
Here is a sample code i hope it will help you.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.anydomain.com/anyapi.php?a=parameters');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
echo $content;
?>
```

Make it sure your query string is properly encoded. 
You need to build your URL using http_build_query, which will take care of urlencoding.

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data)

Output: foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor
```